# AWS EC2 instance in private subnet unable to connect to internet via NAT gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-nat-gateway

I have two EC2 instances, one on public subnet(10.1.1.0/24) and one on private subnet (10.1.2.0/24)
EC2 instance in public subnet works fine with internet connectivity and configured services.

There is a NAT Gateway configured in the public subnet 10.1.1.0/24 with Elastic IP.
Default route on private subnet is [0.0.0.0/0 --> NAT Gateway in public subnet].
I have a custom network ACL on private subnet, what I observed is when source and destination for inbound/outbound rules is set to 10.1.1.0/24 (public subnet) external connectivity breaks, but ssh works.
Only when source/destination are set to 'any' does internet connectivity restore.
I am trying to understand what exact source/destination should be used in network ACLs on private subnet for internet connectivity to work.

Comment: Have you allowed internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0) in your NACL? If you don't allow it, there won't be any internet traffic allowed.

Comment: _WHY_ do you have a custom NACL configured? In general, it is best to leave the NACLs at their default "allow all" setting, unless there is a particular need (eg creating a DMZ).

Answer (score 0):

To allow instance from private subnet access internet using NAT gateway, your NACLs or SG **must allow internet traffic**. The NAT does not change the internet traffic into private VPC traffic. So if you remove `0.0.0.0/0` the internet connectivity stops.

This is explained in AWS docs on [Instances cannot access the internet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-no-internet-connection):

> Ensure that the network ACLs that are associated with the **private subnet** and public subnets **do not have rules that block inbound or outbound internet traffic**.

Therefore, you must allow `0.0.0.0/0` (or some IP range if you want only part of internet traffic) in your NACL and SG for the instances in private subnet.

As a side note, generally NACLs are not modified, and default settings are usually used. Instead security groups are the first choice of controlling access to and from the instances.